# Non repeating section from repeating section

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, infopath2010, infopath-2007

Can some one help me convert a section to non repetitive which is inside a repeating section.

I tried using the preceding-sibling but no use

```
count(preceding-sibling::my:group3) > 0
```

I have attached the sample workbook for your easy references

[Non Repeating Section from repeating section](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqSR8kJy_9vDhD5sexa_hkb5W-Rk?e=AMs4kw)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osqzr.png)

The highlighted yellow section to be fixed for first row of repeating table after that it should be hidden

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my solution

please find below:

```
count(../preceding-sibling::my:group2)
```

[Attachment Solution](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqSR8kJy_9vDhEHD34PSLA84MBJ2?e=wHqtPS)